# $http.post always returns an error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the following code in a js file for my data access:

```
GroupsApp.factory('availableQuestionRepository', function ($http, $q) {
var factory = {};

factory.get = function (groupID) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = "questiongrouping/AvailableQuestions/";
        url = url.concat(groupID)
        $http.get(url).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

factory.save = function (availableQuestions) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post("questiongrouping/PostQuestions", availableQuestions)
        .success(function () { deferred.resolve(); })
        .error(function () { deferred.reject(); });
    return deferred.promise;
};

return factory;
})
```

And the controller is as follows below:

```
GroupsApp.controller("availableQuestions", function ($scope, availableQuestionRepository, msgBus) {
$scope.$on('GroupChanged', function () {
    loadAvailableQuestions();
});

$scope.save = function (aq) {
    availableQuestionRepository.save(aq).then(
        function () { alert("sucess") },
        function () { alert("error") });
}

function loadAvailableQuestions() {
    availableQuestionRepository.get(msgBus.groupID).then(function (AvailableQuestions) { $scope.availableQuestions = AvailableQuestions });

}
});
```

The MVC controller code is as follows:

```
Function PostQuestions(result As List(Of QuestionRO)) As ActionResult
    Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
End Function
```

Why is it when I go to the page in chrome it will always pop up the error alert? I have tried it in IE 10 and it will pop up the success alert box.

Comment: What error is shown in the Chrome debug tools?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any errors in the chrome debug tool. Where should I be looking for the errors?

Comment: You should see an error on the network tab for the HTTP request to questionGroup/PostQuestions

Comment: I put a break point on my server side code I will get a "Caution: Provisional Headers are shown". When I click continue on my server side code the http request will disappear from the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what is causing my problem. The problem was including the tag:

```
<form class="form">

</form>
```

Once I deleted this tag the button for submitting data worked correctly.